# ejb3 Transaction Propagation through finder query methods

Tags: ejb-3.0, jboss5.x, stateless-session-bean

I have Entity and a wrapper class. A wrapper class does all operations like create, remove and find on Entity Bean as below

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student_info")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "findByName", query = " SELECT DISTINCT o FROM StudentBean o WHERE o.studentName = ?1 ") })
public class StudentBean implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="student_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int studentId;

@Column(name="student_name")
private String studentName;

public StudentBean() {
}

public StudentBean(String name) {
    setStudentName(name);
}

public int getStudentId() {
    return this.studentId;
}

public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
}

public String getStudentName(){
    return this.studentName;
}

public void setStudentName(String studentName){
    this.studentName=studentName;
}
 }
```

And the Wrapper class

```
@Stateless
public class StudentClient implements StudentClientLocal {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public StudentBean create(String name) {
    StudentBean bean = new StudentBean(name);
    em.persist(bean);
    return bean;    
}

@Override
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
public StudentBean findByName(java.lang.String studentName) {
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("findByName");
    query.setParameter(1, studentName);
    return (StudentBean) query.getSingleResult();
}

@Override
public void remove(StudentBean bean) {
    em.remove(bean);    
}
}
```

And Now using Manager class, I am checking duplicate student names and if not duplicate adding it to the Student Entity Table.

```
@Stateless
@Local
public class StudentManager implements StudentManagerLocal {

@Resource
private SessionContext context;

private static StudentClientLocal StudentClientLocal;

public StudentManager() {
    try {
        Context context1 = new InitialContext();
        StudentClientLocal = (StudentClientLocal) context1
                .lookup("StudentClient/local");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
@Override
public boolean addStudentAndGroup(StudentBean student,
        StudentGroupBean group) {
    if (student != null) {
        try {
            if(StudentClientLocal.findByName(student.getStudentName()) != null){
                System.out.println("Studnet name exists");
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        try {
            StudentClientLocal.create(student.getStudentName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
}
}
```

The above case following Exception has been thrown.

```
 javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: EntityManager must be access within a transaction
org.jboss.ejb3.tx.Ejb3TxPolicy.handleInCallerTx(Ejb3TxPolicy.java:115)
org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInCallerTx(TxPolicy.java:130)
org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:194)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:186)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.asynchronous.AsynchronousInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousInterceptor.java:106)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.invoke(SessionSpecContainer.java:219)
org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.handler.ProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:261)
org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.handler.session.SessionSpecProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionSpecProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:101)
$Proxy122.create(Unknown Source)
studentejb.StudentManager.addStudentAndGroup(StudentManager.java:64)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.java:69)
org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:73)
org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:59)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:72)
org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_26624628.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_26624628.java)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:88)
org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_26624628.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_26624628.java)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:68)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:79)
org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:190)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:186)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.asynchronous.AsynchronousInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousInterceptor.java:106)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.invoke(SessionSpecContainer.java:219)
org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.handler.ProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:261)
org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.handler.session.SessionSpecProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionSpecProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:101)
$Proxy128.addStudentAndGroup(Unknown Source)
api.GroupManager.addStudentAndGroup(GroupManager.java:31)
com.student.controller.ManageStudentServlet.doPost(ManageStudentServlet.java:81)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
root casue:
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: EntityManager must be access within a transaction
org.jboss.jpa.deployment.ManagedEntityManagerFactory.verifyInTx(ManagedEntityManagerFactory.java:155)
org.jboss.jpa.tx.TransactionScopedEntityManager.persist(TransactionScopedEntityManager.java:186)
interfaces.StudentClient.create(StudentClient.java:25)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.java:69)
org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:73)
org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:59)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:72)
org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_26624628.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_26624628.java)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:88)
org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_26624628.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_26624628.java)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:68)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInCallerTx(TxPolicy.java:126)
org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:194)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:186)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.asynchronous.AsynchronousInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousInterceptor.java:106)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.invoke(SessionSpecContainer.java:219)
org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.handler.ProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:261)
org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.handler.session.SessionSpecProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionSpecProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:101)
$Proxy122.create(Unknown Source)
studentejb.StudentManager.addStudentAndGroup(StudentManager.java:64)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.java:69)
org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:73)
org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:59)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:72)
org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_26624628.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_26624628.java)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:88)
org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_26624628.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_26624628.java)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:68)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:79)
org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:190)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:186)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.asynchronous.AsynchronousInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousInterceptor.java:106)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.invoke(SessionSpecContainer.java:219)
org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.handler.ProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:261)
org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.handler.session.SessionSpecProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionSpecProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:101)
$Proxy128.addStudentAndGroup(Unknown Source)
api.GroupManager.addStudentAndGroup(GroupManager.java:31)
com.student.controller.ManageStudentServlet.doPost(ManageStudentServlet.java:81)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

If I annoted the finder method with Transaction attribute REQUIRED_NEW, NEVER . No exception has been thrown.

```
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public StudentBean findByName(java.lang.String studentName) {
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("findByName");
    query.setParameter(1, studentName);
    return (StudentBean) query.getSingleResult();
}
```

Could please let know the inputs. why the transaction is not propagating through finder method. Is transaction related with managed or detached entity of finder method?

Answer (score 0):

The Exception in finder method is causing the problem. It is started working after i handle exception in the finder method as below.

```
    public StudentBean findByName(java.lang.String studentName) {
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("findByName");
    query.setParameter(1, studentName);
    try {
    return (StudentBean) query.getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException e){
        return null;
    }
}
```